# Hibernate Mapping Error: MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, annotations, mapping

I have a project with Hibernate.I tried to read the configuration file hibernate.cfg and got this error:

```
 Error creando una factoria de session.org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com/david/Categoria"/>
jun 04, 2013 10:19:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [ControladorLibros] en el contexto con ruta [/App01HTML] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción] con causa raíz
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com/david/Categoria"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1479)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1458)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1432)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1352)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1338)
    at com.david.HibernateHelper.buildSessionFactory(HibernateHelper.java:13)
```

my configuration file is so simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/arquitecturajava</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com/david/Categoria"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com/david/Libro"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

don´t accept mapping class lines.

I create de configurations similar to this code:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() 
    {
        try
        {

            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) 
        {
            System.err.println("Error creando una factoria de session." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

and my project libraries are:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using? BTW, the fuly qualified name of a class is com.david.Categoria and not com/david/Categoria.

Comment: The error is the same with com/david/Categoria or com.david.Categoria.

Comment: My version of Hibernate is < 4 but i´m not sure is is 3.5 or 3.3 or other.

Comment: Looking at the name of the jar would help. 3.3 and 3.5 are old versions. You should update to the latest 3.x version at least.

Comment: I don´t have only a any folder with all of jar´s. Initially i downloaded this rar: hibernate-search-4.3.0.CR1. But i couldn´t operate it, so i have downloaded jar to jar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the Hibernate Annotation library in your classpath. You can add it manually, downloading it from Hibernate site, or you can add this Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

And then use the class `AnnotationConfiguration` instead of Configuration to configure your `sessionFactory`.

```
return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Then you have to correct the qualified name of the class, as @JB Nizet suggested you in his comment.

I think this will solve your problem.

EDIT: sorry, I think you have the annotations library in your classpath, just use the `AnnotationConfiguration` class instead of `Configuration` when you build your `sessionFactory`.

Comment: +1, although this is only necessary wil old versions of Hibernate. AnnotationConfiguration is now deprecated, and everything it did has been migrated to Configuration.

Comment: AnnotatioConfiguration don´t exist in org.hibernate.cfg package. Is deprecated. And i´m not using maven. I have added hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar library.

Comment: eternay or JB Nizet, do you know what libraries are neccesary to add, for example with Hibernate 4.3, last version?

Comment: Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/, download the version ou want: it contains all the jars hibernate needs.

Comment: Using Hibernate 4.1.7 through Ivy, I have hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final, antlr-2.7.7, jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA, jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final, dom4j-1.6.1, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final, javassist-3.15.0-GA and hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final. You should use Maven or Ivy to control all this.

Comment: JB Nizet, it´s true!! Perfect!! But i don´t like add all of libraries at once, because i don´t use all. I´ll try to remove not use. So a lo t of thank´s, was so simple..

Comment: In Hibernate 3.5, AnnotationConfiguration wasn't deprecated, but it was in Hibernate 3.6. But you should find the class in your org.hibernate.cfg package. I see a typo in your comment (missing the final 'n' to Annotation), maybe it's the reason why you can't find the class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was of libraries.
This is the solutions:

[image]

A lot of thank´s to Eternay and JB Nizet.